# Create list of x,y,z coordinates using loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I would like to create 3-dimensional array including coordinates of the points in cartesian axis system.
My user input is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rows = int(input("Please Enter the Total Number of Rows  : "))
columns = int(input("Please Enter the Total Number of Columns  : "))
levels = int(input("Please Enter the Total Number of Levels  : "))

dx = int(input("Please Enter the Pitch in x Direction  : "))
dy = int(input("Please Enter the Pitch in y Direction  : "))
dz = int(input("Please Enter the Pitch in z Direction  : "))

x0 = int(input("Please Enter the Origin Coordinate in x Direction  : "))
y0 = int(input("Please Enter the Origin Coordinate in y Direction  : "))
z0 = int(input("Please Enter the Origin Coordinate in z Direction  : "))
```

I want to start at point with coordinates [x0,y0,z0] and then create the 3D array based on the inserted number of rows,columns, levels (3rd dimension) and spacing between the points (dx,dy,dz)

I am think about the loop

```
Data=np.zeros(('rows','columns','levels'))
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(columns):
        for k in range(levels):
```

but no idea how to write this code. Can anyone help? Output should be in form of 3D Array.

Many Thanks
Lukas

Comment: Which distance do you want when you say "spacing between the points"?

Comment: dx, dy, dz are the spacing in individual directions

Comment: Well, you need 3 coordinates (dx, dy, dz) in a 3-dimensional space to make one point. With which other point would you like to measure the distance?
And to make another thing clear, you want to create a `rows*columns*levels` matrix containing points that each have different coordinates of origin?

Comment: No Lorenzo. You didn´t get it right. Let´s imagine it grafically. I want to create 3D rectangular pattern. I know number of rows and columns in 2D and number of levels to extend it to 3D. I have spacing/distance/pitch between the coordinates in each direction called dx,dy,dz... As it shouldn´t generally start at coordinate 0,0,0, I insert also the coordinates of the first point as user input (x0,y0,z0).I want to get 3D array of computed coordinates. Each point is given by (x,y,z) coordinate. The absolut ouput will be csv consisting of 4 columns (point ID, x-coord, y-coord, z-coord)

Answer (score 0):

Set `x, y, z` as vectors

```
x = x0 + np.arange(rows)    * dx
y = y0 + np.arange(columns) * dy
z = z0 + np.arange(levels)  * dz
```

Now make 3x arrays of shape `(rows, columns, levels)` with `np.meshgrid`

```
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)
```

Now you can make your scalar field just using those variables

```
Data = X**2 + Y**2 + Z**2  # for example
```

Your `Data` will now be a `(rows, columns, levels)`-shaped array, with dimensional axes corresponding to `x, y, z`